# An issue with array push

Tags: perl

I have two hashes which I use in my code. One,

```
Dumper \%userJobCount

$VAR1 = {
          'hina' => 2,
          'maccetta' => 1,
          'vineethk' => 1,
          'jpriyank' => 27,
          'sanchars' => 1,
          'kamran' => 8,
          'wilt' => 7,
          'sakir' => 5,
          'rjernigan' => 8,
          'emichael' => 1,
          'ranjith' => 8,
          'wgutknec' => 7,
          'danchuy' => 1,
          'saurabh4' => 1,
          'chengc' => 9,
          'revathi' => 2,
          'zumach' => 7,
          'hual' => 7,
          'lkashyap' => 2,
          'raviteja' => 17,
          'bsheetal' => 4,
          'horgan' => 2,
          'tongz' => 6,
          'demat' => 1,
          'matthew6' => 14,
          'alward' => 1,
          'adalton' => 1,
          'sydneyw' => 5,
          'yashodhc' => 1,
          'makam' => 1,
          'surajs' => 9,
          'radish' => 2,
          'sudiptac' => 2,
          'adityak' => 4,
          'dodgson' => 4,
          'sudipp' => 6,
          'zaw' => 1,
          'umeshr' => 23,
          'zukas' => 6
        };
```

and

```
%userJobSubtest = (
        name      => '',
        username  => '', 
        rc        => PASS,
        notes     => ''
    );
```

Here's the code where I use them:

```
foreach my $key (keys %userJobCount) {
    if( $userJobCount{$key} > $jobLimit) {
        %userJobSubtest = (
            name      => $key,
            username  => $key, 
            rc        => WARN,
            notes     => ''
        );
        #print Dumper \%userJobSubtest;
        push(@{$rtn{subtests}}, \%userJobSubtest);
    }
}
print Dumper %rtn;
```

I'll just show the subtests key value from the total output:

```
$VAR6 = [
          {
            'rc' => 3,
            'notes' => '',
            'name' => 'umeshr',
            'username' => 'umeshr'
          },
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0],
          $VAR6->[0]
        ];
```

In the code, this part is commented out:

```
#print Dumper \%userJobSubtest;
```

When I run this, it has the values of other keys whose values are more than the $jobLimit (= 5)
Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong with the push? Why am I getting duplicate entries when what I am pushing shouldn't actually be the same value?

Comment: PS - You'll get better results if you pass references to hashes and arrays to `Dumper`. For example, `print Dumper %rtn;` should be `print Dumper \%rtn;`. In this case, print Dumper $rtn{subtests};` would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made every element of `@{ $rtn{subtests} }` a reference to the *same* hash.

Fix:

```
my %userJobSubtest = (
    name      => $key,
    username  => $key, 
    rc        => WARN,
    notes     => ''
);

push(@{$rtn{subtests}}, \%userJobSubtest);
```

The `my` creates a variable. Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!

Comment: That worked. The code had `use strict; use warnings;` What's the difference introduced with `use warnings qw (all);` ?

Comment: That means you were also clobbering some other hash, and that you now have two variables with the same name in scope. Rename one of them.

Comment: I didn't understand one thing. The reference to `\%userJobSubtest` should point to `%userJobSubtest`. So, when the value of `%userJobSubtest` changes, shouldn't the reference also point to the new value? I'm sorry, I get confused with references.

Comment: Re "*shouldn't the reference also point to the new value?*", Yes, and it did. That's the problem you asked us to fix. By replacing the single `%userJobSubtest`  with a new one created each pass of the loop, the problem goes away.

Comment: That's right and it got solved because I re-declared the hash using `my`. What I meant to ask is why is the `my` important here? Without using the `my`, why isn't the reference pointing to the new value after I changed the value of the hash? Why does it still point to the old value?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer and as I clarified in my last comment, `my` creates a new var *each time it's executed*. You don't have one hash anymore. Your references are to different hashes.